# How to display multiline notification on react native android?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have create a notification like this:

```
const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
    .setNotificationId('1')
    .setTitle('Reminder')
    .setBody('Looooooooooooooooooooooonggggggg messageeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee longggggggggggggg messsssssagggeeeeeeeeee')
    .setData({
      key: true,
      data: {},
    })
    .android.setChannelId('test-channel')
    .android.setAutoCancel(true)
    .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max);
```

I want to show all the body message on notification. But it only show one line message.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bigText prop in android object. You can see the documentation here https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/reference/AndroidNotification#setBigText but to summerize it something like this shoudlwork

```
const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
    .setNotificationId('1')
    .setTitle('Reminder')
    .setBody('Looooooooooooooooooooooonggggggg messageeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee longggggggggggggg messsssssagggeeeeeeeeee')
    .setData({
      key: true,
      data: {},
    })
    .android.setChannelId('test-channel')
    .android.setAutoCancel(true)
    .android.setBigText('Looooooooooooooooooooooonggggggg messageeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee longggggggggggggg messsssssagggeeeeeeeeee')
    .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max);
```